# How to create a button in storyboard to start a game created with spritekit in xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a really simple game in xcode using spritekit and swift. Now I want to have a main menu that shows up when I first start the app. Then i want to have a button that when tapped on, will start the game. Is there a way to do this? Should i be using story board? thanks so much! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Main Menu In Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665676/main-menu-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

By using `SpriteKit` you can do it this way:

In your `GameViewController.swift` replace your code with this code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //load your GameScene from viewController
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)

    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

This code will load `GameScene` when you start your game.

Add this code in your `GameScene.swift` class:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    //create playbutton instance
    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "play_unpresed")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        addPlayButton()  //add playbutton
    }

    func addPlayButton(){

        playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        playButton.xScale = 0.2
        playButton.yScale = 0.2
        self.addChild(playButton)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>){
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            //this will detect touch on play button
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton {
                //it will transits to the next scene
                let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
                let letsPlay = playScene(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(letsPlay, transition: reveal)

            }
        }

    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

This will load a scene with one button now when you press a button it will take you to your `playScene` And for that you have to create a new file by clicking Command + N then iOS Source -> Cocoa Touch class -> next -> add class name playScene -> Subclass of SKScene -> and create it.

Add `import SpriteKit` in your `playScene.swift`

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=55943772211582353399) sample project for more info.

And [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners) is the easy tutorial for spriteKit.

Comment: how do i launch the game by creating the cocoa touch class?

Comment: just select spriteKit when you create a new game.

Comment: If i replace the code in gameviewcontroller then my game will not work properly?

Comment: I suggest you to read the tutorial which I suggest you in my answer and it will give you basic knowledge about spriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just drag one viewController to the storyBoard.
2. set it `Is Initial View Controller`, add one button on it
3. `control+drag` from the button to your Game View Controller. choose `show`

[image]

I've test it. It can work. When I click the button, It will navigate to the Game view controller

Comment: hold `control` key, use your mouse left click on the button, don't release, It will show a segue line, darg it to your `sprite view controller`

Answer (score 0):

## Storyboards

Alternatively, you can use Storyboards. In the [M.W.E.](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflowSKSpriteKit)  for another S.O. question they have a basic "menu" set up.

In your case, what you would do is:

- go to Main.storyboard.
- on the right-hand tool bar, find view controller
- drag view-controller into Main.storyboard
- click on the new view-controller
- click - on the right-hand tool bar - the identity inspector (looks like a business card)
- change Class to GameViewController
- click on view within the hierarchy on the left (under the new view controller)
- click the identity inspector
- change class to SKView
- click on the original view controller
- click on the identity inspector
- change class to UIViewController
- click on the view within the original UIViewController
- click on identity inspector
- change class to UIView
- find button at the bottom of the right-hand side tool bar
- drag it onto the first view
- right click drag from the button to the second view
- on the pop-up menu, under action segue, click show
- right click drag from the button up, add horizontally center constraints
- right click drag from the button to the right, add vertically center constraints

*Images*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]