# Main Menu In Swift

Tags: swift, menu, transition, program-entry-point

I would like to create a main menu for my game in swift.

I am using the following code:

```
import SpriteKit
```

class menuScene: SKScene {

```
//Adding Start Button
let startButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButton")



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    //Temporary Background
    backgroundColor = SKColor.darkGray

    //Start Button
    startButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(startButton)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self);  //Finding location of touch

        if atPoint(location) == startButton {

            if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                view!.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 1))
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run this however, My app crashes and highlights if atPoint(location) == startButton {. with "Thread 1, Breakpoint 1.1"

Im not entirely sure what this is but I hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: When I ran this and compiled it on my own device, nothing crashed.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the line?

Comment: Try using `if startButton.containsPoint(location)` instead or check that you did not accidentally set any breakpoint. If you see a small blue rectangle on the line number, you have a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks guys! The beginner I am put a breakpoint in. Duh!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Custom `SKViews`

Let's say, like this [M.W.E.](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflowSKSpriteKit), you want a menu, a difficulty, and a game scene.

Then you can make a series of custom `SKViews` to transition between.

[image]

#### GameViewController

This code loads the menuScene:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let menuScene = MenuScene(size: view.bounds.size)

    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    menuScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(menuScene)

}
```

#### MenuScene

```
class MenuScene: SKScene {

    let playButton = SKLabelNode()


    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        playButton.fontColor = SKColor.black
        playButton.text = "play"

        playButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)

        addChild(playButton)

    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

        if playButton.contains(touchLocation) {

            let reveal = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 0.5)
            let difficultyScene = DifficultyScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(difficultyScene, transition: reveal)

        }

    }


}
```

#### DifficultyScene

```
class DifficultyScene: SKScene {

    let easyButton = SKLabelNode()
    let hardButton = SKLabelNode()
    let menuButton = SKLabelNode()


    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        easyButton.fontColor = SKColor.black
        easyButton.text = "easy"

        hardButton.fontColor = SKColor.black
        hardButton.text = "hard"

        menuButton.fontColor = SKColor.black
        menuButton.text = "menu"

        easyButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        hardButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2 - easyButton.fontSize * 2)
        menuButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 4 * 3, y: size.height / 4)

        addChild(easyButton)
        addChild(hardButton)
        addChild(menuButton)

    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

        if easyButton.contains(touchLocation) {
            let reveal = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 0.5)
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size, difficulty: easyButton.text!)
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
        }

        if hardButton.contains(touchLocation) {
            let reveal = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 0.5)
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size, difficulty: hardButton.text!)
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
        }

        if menuButton.contains(touchLocation){
            let reveal = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 0.5)
            let menuScene = MenuScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(menuScene, transition: reveal)
        }

    }


}
```

#### GameScene

add this to your `GameScene`:

```
init(size: CGSize, difficulty: String) {
        super.init(size: size)
        gameDifficulty = difficulty
    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

---

## Storyboards

Alternatively, you can use Storyboards. In the [M.W.E.](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflowSKSpriteKit)  for another S.O. question they have a basic "menu" set up.

In your case, what you would do is:

- go to Main.storyboard.
- on the right-hand tool bar, find view controller
- drag view-controller into Main.storyboard
- click on the new view-controller
- click - on the right-hand tool bar - the identity inspector (looks like a business card)
- change Class to GameViewController
- click on view within the hierarchy on the left (under the new view controller)
- click the identity inspector
- change class to SKView
- click on the original view controller
- click on the identity inspector
- change class to UIViewController
- click on the view within the original UIViewController
- click on identity inspector
- change class to UIView
- find button at the bottom of the right-hand side tool bar
- drag it onto the first view
- right click drag from the button to the second view
- on the pop-up menu, under action segue, click show
- right click drag from the button up, add horizontally center constraints
- right click drag from the button to the right, add vertically center constraints

*Images*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]