# Swift: SKSpriteKit, using Storyboards, UIViewController and UIButton to set in game parameters?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uistoryboard, skscene

## Context

The default code that comes with a new `SpriteKit` game has a storyboard such that - following the launch screen - all there is, is a `GameViewController` which calls forth the `GameScene`. However, this may be less ideal for many games. For example, one may wish to have the user select difficulty from a main menu, and then go to the `GameScene` - outlined below:

[image: Storyboard]

Notably, the middle view controller is a custom class `MyUIViewController` so that the `UIButtons` "easy" and "hard" can have the following `IBActions`:

```
   @IBAction func setGameDifficultyToEasy(sender: AnyObject) {
        gameDifficulty = "easy"
        print("Game difficulty set to \(gameDifficulty)")
    }
    
    @IBAction func setGameDifficultyToHard(sender: AnyObject) {
        gameDifficulty = "hard"
        print("Game difficulty set to \(gameDifficulty)")
    }
```

where `gameDifficulty` is a global variable, that the `GameScene` utilizes to determine aspects of the game play.

In the M.W.E. setting `gameDifficulty` to "hard" causes there to be three sprites on the screen, whereas setting `gameDifficulty` to "easy" puts forth only two.

**Easy**
[image: Easy]

**Hard**
[image: Hard]

## Question

In the following gif, one sees that:

- `gameDifficuly` is initialized as "hard"
- the `UIButton` "Easy" was selected.

This can be seen be the printout statements.

[image: Demo Gif]

Interestingly, although the `UIButton` was pressed *first* then the `GameViewController` was called, the changing of the parameter `gameDifficulty` was not set until *after* the `GameScene` was rendered.

**How can I get the `UIButton`s to set the parameter `gameDifficulty` prior to `GameScene` being called?

## Minimum Working Example

[Stack Overflow SKSpriteKit](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflowSKSpriteKit)

## Note

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789989/5623899) shows that this is clearly possible, but by relegating everything to `SKView`s rather than using a `storyboard`. So if possible, please keep answers related to using `storyboard`s.

Comment: You can use `userData` property of your scene as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41836339/1894067)